# Phonegap build for tablet and/or smartphone

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using phonegap build to build my apps for iOS, Android and Windows.
How do I specify (in config.xml probably) that phonegap build should build only for tablets, or only for smartphones or for both across all three platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for iOS you can set the `target-device` [preference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/config_ref/index.html) to "handset" in config.xml:

```
<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
```

For android, you'll need to [edit the manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) in a cordova [hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html)... Like `after_prepare` or `after_platform_add`

For windows... hum... Joker!

Comment: Tnx. I think I understand for iOS, I'll take a look for android. And what do you mean "joker" for windows? :) I actually don't need anything for windows now, I'm building only for smartphones, but there are windows laptops that can turn into tablets, in future I might need to build for that too.

Comment: I mean Windows, I don't know/care ! :-)

Comment: as this led me to the right answer (and is the only answer :)) I'm marking it as correct. I would just like to add this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/config-file-element/